# Why doesn't Array.prototype.some named as .any?

Tags: javascript

`any` sounds more native, and `some` kind of implies the number of items matching the predicate matters.

Why does the standard name the method some instead of any?

Comment: Just a guess, but some popular library probably monkey-patched an 'any' method on to `Array.prototype` already.

Comment: IIRC that was one of a number of methods named in a way that would minimize conflict with existing sites.

Comment: @zzzzBov so existing libraries took the best name and the standard has to pick a weird name.. it's so sad..

Answer (score 4):

It was because of [prototype.js,](http://prototypejs.org/) which added an `Iterable.any` method to the prototype of arrays. This practice is now frowned upon for good reasons, but prototype was one of the earliest libraries and IIRC was also following rails lead (rails monkey-patches Ruby's built-in classes).

TC-39 generally will bend over backwards to avoid any breakage, AFAIK the standard practice is to crawl the web and see how widespread usage is, at which point the make a decision which is almost always to pick another name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the history of the name. However, the statement

```
array.some(func)
```

would mathematically be translated as

```
∃ i ∈ {0, …, length(array)-1} : func(array_i, i, array)
```

This is even mentioned in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.some):

> `some` acts like the "exists" quantifier in mathematics.

And the [∃ quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification), in English, is also called "for some".

So "some" seems OK to me.

Comment: That's a good point: the relationship to the existential quantifier.

Comment: In that sense,  `exists` would be better to me.

Comment: @LoveRight But `array.exists(func)` might be confused with `array.includes(func)`. I guess `array.existsItemSuchThat(func)` would work, but it's too long.